# Interacting with a specific checkbox with all having the same type and ID

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to click on a checkbox for a specific row based on input criteria so someone might input say the Number (e.g 9) and the code needs to enable the check box.

However, all of the checkboxes have the same ID and type of `<input "type="checkbox" id="checkBox" style="outline-offset: -2px;">`.

I am trying to use Javascript to do this but I'm not sure if its possible?

[image]

Comment: All the elements having the same `id` is an issue you need to fix as that's invalid HTML. To do what you require put a `data` attribute on the checkboxes relating to their number, then select the elements by that number. If you need a specific example of how to do this, please add all relevant code to the question

Comment: Also, as an aside to what you're asking, avoid putting inline `style` attributes in your HTML. Use external styleshhets to contain your CSS instead. Finally, `pokey` and some other attributes are non-standard and may cause rendering issues. If you want to store custom metadata in an HTML element use a `data` attribute

Comment: Thanks! Yeah its a training webpage I have been provided on a training course I am doing, I'm not sure if it is then possible to interact with a specific checkBox? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Assuming that you're not able to change the HTML it's still possible, but you would have to use a less than ideal approach, ie. Finding the row in the table with the `9` value as text in the second column, then traversing the DOM to find the related checkbox and check it. I'd also call in to question how good the quality of any tutorial is if it's making such basic errors as non-standard HTML.

Comment: The course is for an automation tool with some kinda adhoc made web pages, I'm not sure if they were wanting us to do this I was just exploring options and seeing if I could automate deleting records as the framework runs on JS for interacting with browsers. Thanks for your input - this is all a learning curve for me @RoryMcCrossan